# window.history.pushState and cookies conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, web

When I'm using window.history.pushState to change url in address string, my cookies were deleted, or better to say were set to some old value after i have reloaded the page. I'm using jquery-cookie plugin (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). If I don't click the button, that calling window.history.pushState, everything is OK, cookies are fine. What can be the reason of it?